# Como acessar a main thread a partir da thread principal

Tags: c#, unity3d

gostaria de saber se é possivel chamar um metodo usando uma thread a partir de outra thread.
O motivo é que existem metodos que só podem ser chamados da thread principal, e preciso chama-los em outra thread.

Answer (score 0):

A Main thread irá precisar de invocação, durante a depuração irá mostrar um erro quando você operar uma operação Cross-Thread, mas essa exceção será inexistente na hora do Release.

Se a sua Thread é um `Form`, você pode invocar com esse código:

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => SuaFuncao()));
    return;
}
```

Seja `SuaFuncao()` o método que o Thread iria executar.

Em .NET 2.0 seria o equivalente à:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {MyFunction();});
```

Para aplicativos de Console:

```
var mydelegate = new Action<object>(delegate(object param)
{
    Console.WriteLine(param.ToString());
});
mydelegate.Invoke("test");
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123061/calling-methods-in-main-thread-from-other-threads)